# Can not select parts of the mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, faces, uv-image-editor

Hey I am new to the program not sure what I did wrong here. I can't select any vertices, faces or edges on the tongue and gums of my model, which I need to in order to colour them in UV Editing mode. I appreciate any sort of help!

[image]

Comment: you are in edit mode for a different object.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not editing the tongue and gums.  Try exiting edit mode, selecting one of them, and then switching back.  That should fix it.